# Wait for a variable to change value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have a textbox, and everytime the user presses a key, I compute the field's new length to see how many characters are still available.
Based on that number, I :

1. check if the "send" button should be enabled or not
2. check if the counter that displays the length should be red or black (à la twitter)

But now I have a problem; on each *keydown* event, I do :

```
remaining = 100 - count;

if (remaining > 9)
{
    //blue counter; send is activated
    //"if counter.class == red then counter.class = blue..."
    //"send.off('click'); send.on('click', sendmessage)..."
}
else if ((remaining <= 9) && (remaining >= 0))
{
    //red counter; send is activated
}
else //remaining <0
{
    //red counter; send is deactivated
}
```

Each time the user presses a key, one of the 3 blocs is executed... Isn't there a way to execute the blocs only when the variable changes "zone" ( `]∞, 9[`; `[9,0]`; `]0; -∞[`) ?

Comment: How can the count be less than zero?

Comment: my bad, it's actually the count of caracters remaining (again, like twitter with the 140 limit)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? (I notice the `send.off(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt this could be done more elegantly, but the simple answer is just to remember the previous value of the length:

```
var prevCount = 10;

function checkLength() {
   var count = // your logic to get current count here

   if (count > 9 && prevCount <=9) {
      // count has changed to > 9
   } else if (count <=9 && count >= 0 && (prevCount > 9 || prevCount < 0) {
      // count has changed to <=9
   } else if (count < 0 && prevCount >= 0) {
      // count has changed to < 0
   }

   prevCount = count;
}
```

Initialise `prevCount` to whatever value makes sense when the screen loads...

(P.S. How can the count be less than zero?)

**Update:** Since you've confirmed that you're using jQuery you could do something like this (assumes "black" and "red" are classes in your stylesheet with the appropriate colours and formatting setup):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 100,
        $rem = $("#remaining").addClass("black"),
        $send = $("input");

    $("textarea").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length,
            remaining = limit - len;

        $rem.text(remaining);
        $send.prop("disabled", len === 0 || remaining < 0);

        if (remaining <=9 && $rem.hasClass("black")
            || remaining > 9 && $rem.hasClass("red"))
            $rem.toggleClass("black red");
    }).keydown();
});​
```

Disables the send button if there's no text or too much text; changes the class from black to red only when necessary. (You could also make black the default and just toggle the "red" class on and off.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAjez/